# Color gradation mismatch in bitmap brushes Ai

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, brush, bitmap

I'm experiencing a color difference between an original psd file and the brush created with that same file. File is a Grayscale + 2 pantone file where only pantone have information. Grayscale is only to avoid impossibility to import multichannel files in Ai. Can anyone explain why and a way to go around this please ?

Also do any of You know a way to overlap the brush ends in order to avoid the gap noticeable ?
[image]
Thank you !

Comment: I can reproduce the issues you have here. [See this gif](https://i.imgur.com/pm6a1Fc.gif). I embed an image with the same two Pantone colors at 100% and 50%. When I apply the brush to a straight line the tints seem correct, but as soon as I add just one more point, the 50% tints get lighter. They even seem to get gradually lighter along the line. And it's not because they somehow get converted to CMYK/RGB, they *are* still spot colors. Additionally I also experience a noticeable gap which I'm not able to fix.

Comment: @Wolff The gap looks like a conflation artefact TBH. Not sure there's really a way to fix that.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I should have zoomed in on the gif.  It doesn't like like a conflation artefact. There is a measurable ragged gap. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/EDWRpIc.png) and [this](https://i.imgur.com/UXvP2T7.png).

Comment: Wolf that's exactly what I mean. And it's really bad when you use it on a batch of arts some straight ( not deformed or converted in brushes ). They come out different from each other when the original fine is the same. That is very amateur error for such a great tool.

Comment: @Wolff, yeah I saw that too when I tried to replicate it.  Could be a potential bug, which would make it off-topic here. The OP should probably contact Adobe to report it. Of course, that doesn't mean it will ever get fixed.  Also, it may be asking a bit much to expect a vector image editor to handle raster graphics well. Might be better to attempt this in Photoshop to be honest.